# A doubt on Kalki avatar

Tags: vishnu, kalki

The Kalki avatar is the last avatar of Lord Vishnu (or) final avatar of Dashavatara. Why did Lord Vishnu take up this form or avatar? Why is he riding a white horse and why he is carrying a sword in his hand?

Comment: The reasons for Lord Vishnu taking any avatar are always the same viz-eradicating evil & restoring dharma on earth.What kind of specific reasons are u looking for?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by this form or avtar? Are you asking why he is riding a white horse and/or why he is carrying a sword in his end? Which particular aspect of the Kalki avtar are you referring to?

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't mention in the question sir

Comment: @Rickross - The first two of Vishnu, avtars Matsya and Kurma were not eradicating evil and restoring dharma directly. Matsya was for saving people from the flood while Kurma was for becoming the support base on which samudra manthan took place.

Comment: @SwamiFactanand--Fitting answer

Comment: @SwamiFactanand since the Q is about Kalki ,and he is to be born as human i was talking about similar avataras/